# Обращение к файлу (exe) внутри Jar

Tags: java, maven, selenium

Здравствуйте, вот класс который обращается к хромдрайверу, работая в еклипсе всё отрабатывает хорошо.Как только упаковал в jar с помощью maven выскакивает ошибка, что нужно написать в `System.setProperty` чтоб он ссылался на хромдрайвер в jar файле?

```
        public class App {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/main/java/resources/chromedriver.exe");
                ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
                driver.get("https://google.com");    
    }
  }
```

Вот структура проекта [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Экзешник выполняет ОС, а она, конечно, не умеет смотреть в jar, хоть это и примитивный архив. Вам нужно распаковать экзешник перед запуском.

Comment: @etki Хорошо,а когда я распакую то какой будет путь?если всё распаковывать в resources.

Comment: куда распакуете, такой и будет